# Jobs in /etc/cron.d are not working on ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, cron

When I run `php /var/www/html/devices/ac1/cron_on.php` in the terminal it works normally. But nothing happens when I add it in the `/etc/cron.d` directory.

The cron job    `49 11 * * * root php /var/www/html/devices/ac1/cron_on.php`

I also tried `49 11 * * * root /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/devices/ac1/cron_on.php`

And tried without `root`

Comment: What was the file named that you put in /etc/cron.d/? If I recall correctly, files with extensions are ignored.

Comment: Also is the file you put in cron.d owed by root:root (chown root:root <filename>)?

Comment: The file name is 001_on and it is owned by root:root.

Comment: Replace the content of your cron file (in cron.d) with `* * * * * root echo test >> /tmp/cron_temp` and check that file after about a minute to rule out cron. What do you get if you run `service cron status`?
Do you get any hint in `/var/log/syslog` if you look for CRON?

Comment: With "* * * * * root echo test >> /tmp/cron_temp" I get ERROR (Missing newline before EOF, this crontab will be ignored)

Comment: You need to add a new empty line at the end of the file. However, this is progress, cron tries to run the file.

Comment: I did and the error went away. Now it says (root) CMD (php /var/www/html/devices/ac1/cron_on.php^M) but the thingy that is supposed to happen by the php did not happen.

Comment: Great! If you test with the line  `* * * * * root /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/devices/ac1/cron_on.php &> /tmp/log_file` your command will run every minute and the output will be piped to the file /tmp/log_file which you can examine for hints. What does it say? You can also try to run your command as root e.g. `sudo /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/devices/ac1/cron_on.php` to see if the root user causes problems.

Comment: All good. Thank you very much.

Comment: I created an answer. Please consider marking it as an answer if you think it will help others. Also, thank you.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To find the problem and make it work consider the following

- Make sure the script in `/etc/cron.d/` is owned by root:root (`chown root:root /etc/cron.d/*`)
- Make sure the script ends with a newline
- If the script seem to not work try with a simples one e.g. `* * * * * root echo test >> /tmp/cron_temp` and monitor `/tmp/cron_temp`
- `service cron status` will provide hints of how well the line executed
- If the lines executed seems to be the culprit try running it as the user in the cron file `sudo -u username <command-to-be-run>`

Comment: This helped me solved a similar issue... running `service cron status` tells you that the file needs to be chmod 644 as well, which sorted me out.

Comment: This: `Make sure the script ends with a newline`, was the solution for me. Thank!

Comment: for people using systemctl, try:
```systemctl status crond -l```

Comment: Just to add for people like me unfamiliar with cron that the script needs to indicate a username and cron (unfortunately?) only warns about an ill-formed script when it first loads it. So if you have something like `* * * * * echo test >> /tmp/cron_temp` where you are missing a username after the `* * * * *`, then add it to get e.g. `* * * * * root echo test >> /tmp/cron_temp` and it should load fine (you can check you cron logs)

Comment: Make sure files in `/etc/cron.d/` must NOT have a suffix, eg `work.cron` will NOT work.

Comment: Watch cron.service realtime logs: `journalctl -u cron.service -f`

Comment: When writing to log from cron using an user other than root, be sure write permissions are set for this user - that way my case; cron was working but no ourput because of wrong permissions.

Answer (score 3):

I found that having a dot (`.`) in the name of the file caused the cron job to not run.  Removed the dot and everything ran fine.